# Putting DataService calls into Helper classes?

Tags: c#, architecture, mvvm

I have several ViewModels all doing partly the same: del/add/export etc documents. At the moment the code to call these methods lives in the viewmodels. So I have to copy/paste it... When I put that code in a DocumentHelper class I have it only one time, but do you see any reason against calling database methods from a Helper class?

Answer (score 2):

An emphatic **YES**, you should move your code to a helper class.

I am a strong believer in the Pragmatic Programmer's [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.  It is one you should strive to follow, as well.  By copy-and-pasting the code, it makes making changes an obnoxious pain, since you have to find every single place you copied that code and change it there.  The copy-and-paste technique crushes any agility you might have had and makes refactoring a nightmare.

Comment: +1 I agree with Travis; but one extra point - just make sure you don't have any View / Model specific code/references in the helpers. I know it's kind of obvious but there's no harm in high-lighting the point.

Comment: Definitely: You cannot make common that which is not common.

Comment: @Adrian well I have no this using TBM.Model; in my helper class. Thats a "reference" to my Models, is that bad now? I made the DocHelper a static class.

Comment: It's fine if you *use* the model classes in your `DocHelper`, just make sure that you're not storing anything in a `static` variable - have your function use what it provided to it in the arguments and then forget about it.  There is probably a CS word for this, but I can't think of it.  And to reassure you, making the helper class `static` is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment supporting Travis G's comment but I ran out of room - hence this 'answer'.

You want to be careful how you arrange your system regarding dependencies; keep in mind how re-usable you want things to be. If the DocHelper references the model then anytime you want to re-use the Dochelper (say in another app) then you will have to bring across the model as well.

Two possible approaches:

Things that are "common" in the context of the model are located in the model assembly.

```
MyApp.Model  // including Model Helpers
MyApp.Common // contains generic helpers
```

In terms of references, `Model` could reference `Common` - but not the other way around.

Things that are "common" in the context of the model are located in a separate assembly - and that assembly is a dedicated Model "helper"; things that are truly generic should be in a separate assembly, e.g:

```
MyApp.Model
MyApp.ModelHelper // Model helpers are kept separate
MyApp.Common      // contains generic helpers
```

In this case, `Model` would reference `ModelHelper`, and `Model` and/or `ModelHelper` could reference `Common`.

Comment: @Adrin "If the DocHelper references the model then anytime you want to re-use the Dochelper (say in another app) then you will have to bring across the model as well." thats is a nice comment, but I do not think I will reuse that code in another application, just another area of the same application.

Comment: Wrong way around: the Model can reference the DocHelper (but not the other way around).